# Why is this serialization not returning CHECKED checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with checked checkboxes. Its serialization is not returning those checked checkboxes. This is the jQuery code I am using to perform the serialization.

```
$('form.subscribe').serialize()
```

The above serialization returns

```
email=
```

This is the markup:

```
<form class="subscribe">
<div class="body">
    <div class="email input">
        <input name="email" placeholder="your email address" />
    </div>
    <div class="expandable">
        <div class="fieldLabel emphasis">I am a:</div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <input id="isDeveloper" type="checkbox" />
            <label for="isDeveloper">Developler<label> 
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <input id="isDesigner" type="checkbox" />
            <label for="isDesigner">Designer</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <input id="isHR" type="checkbox" />
            <label for="isHR">Talent Coordinator</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <input id="isPM" type="checkbox" />
            <label for="isPM">Project Manager</label>
        </div>
        <div class="fieldLabel emphasis">Email me about:</div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <input id="wantsCollab" type="checkbox" checked="checked"/>
            <label for="wantsCollab">Collaboration</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <input id="wantsBlog" type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
            <label for "wantsBlog">Blog Posts</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="button">
        <input class="emphasis" type="submit" value="subscribe">
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

As you can see, there is 1 text input and 6 checkboxes. 2 of those checkboxes are checked, yet only the text input is being returned in the serialization.

Comment: none of your checkboxes have a name attribute

Comment: For a form element's value to be included in the serialized string, the element must have a name attribute.
-- jquery.com --

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your checkboxes do not have name attributes, and your email input has no type specified. Also your form has no action or encoding specified, which you might want for purposes of graceful degradation.

Answer (score 1):

From the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

> Note: Only "successful controls" are serialized to the string. No
>   submit button value is serialized since the form was not submitted
>   using a button. For a form element's value to be included in the
>   serialized string, **the element must have a name attribute**. Values
>   from checkboxes and radio buttons (inputs of type "radio" or
>   "checkbox") are included only if they are checked. Data from file
>   select elements is not serialized.